# How to store an image after taking it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, imagepicker

I'm trying to build an app using Flutter and I need to store the image after the user takes it using the mobile camera and I don't know how.
I used ImagePicker to take the image, but after that I got stuck.

I tried this code:

```
void picker() {
    Future<File?> captureAndSaveImage() async {
      final pickedImage =
          await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedImage == null) return null;
      try {
        final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (directory != null)
          return File(pickedImage.path).copy('${directory.path}/name.png');
      } catch (e) {
        return null;
        File? file = await captureAndSaveImage();
      }
    }
  }
```

I imported the required packages, but I got the  following error:
The plugin `path_provider` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

my Flutter version is: Flutter 2.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the minimun sdk version to 21

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: edit build.gradle located at android/app/ directory, find the line minSdkVersion and change it to 21